# Jest mock output for prisma.groupBy method

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, prisma

I have a litesql db with a prisma schema that looks like:

```
model Rating {
    id      String @id @default(cuid())
    rating  Float
    userId  String
    videoId String

    @@unique([userId, videoId], name: "user_video_rating")
}
```

and I'm trying to write a unit test for the following function:

```js
const ratings = await prisma.rating.groupBy({
    by: ["videoId"],
    _avg: { rating: true },
    _count: true
});
```

I have written a Jest test as follows:

```js
test("get all ratings", async () => {
    const prismaMock = mockDeep<PrismaClient>();
    // can't figure out how to make a mock output for groupBy()
});
```

As the comment says, I can't figure out how to make a mock output for groupBy(). I'm working in TS, and I've already tried using `prismaMock.rating.groupBy.mockResolvedValue()`, but `mockResolvedValue()` does not exist on `groupBy`. I also tried using the following jest spy codes:

```js
const groupBySpy = jest.spyOn(prismaMock.rating, "groupBy");
groupBySpy.mockReturnValue([]); // i've tried this
groupBySpy.mockImplementation(() => {}); // i've also tried this
```

but I couldn't get either to work because the types that they require seem to be not output data.

I'm not sure how to make a test function work with groupBy, but I don't want to switch `groupBy` to multiple `aggregate({where: })` calls in my logic just because I can't write a unit test for the `groupBy` method. Does anyone have suggestions on what to do regarding unit testing this method or have any experience writing unit tests for `prisma.#.groupBy()` that can help me figure out how to resolve this issue?

Comment: My advice - use a library like MSW (Mock Service Workers) to mock the endpoint you're hitting and provide a result object to test on. Better pattern than mocking modules your code actually uses.

Comment: @Derek I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm building the endpoint right now -- I'm not hitting anything external. As for modules, the PrismaClient is a generated client based on my schema. Can you clarify a bit more please? Thanks!

Comment: `await prisma.rating.groupBy();` - i assume that hits some URL to fetch/post some data? MSW proxys the actual network call to a service worker it spins up when it runs that test, and you tell it what data to return in the call, whether it's successful or not, etc. Your test expectations then deal with the scenarios you need to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it but I don't like the solution so if anyone else has any suggestions about how to make this more elegant please let me know. I fixed it by just assuming the `mockReturnValueOnce` function existed on `prisma.rating.groupBy` even though ts doesn't agree. The following code is what I ended up with:

```js
test("get all ratings", async () => {
    const prismaMock = mockDeep<PrismaClient>();

    const mockRatingOutput = [
        { videoId: 'test-video-0', _avg: { rating: 3.5 }, _count: 2 },
        { videoId: 'test-vide-1', _avg: { rating: 3.5 }, _count: 1 }
    ];

    // @ts-ignore
    prismaMock.rating.groupBy.mockReturnValueOnce(mockRatingOutput);

    // etc...
})
```

This is definitely not optimal because it depends on me manually setting the mock output value, but since I'm not directly testing this function and instead testing logic that requires this function's output, I think that if I assume the prisma function call works as the prisma docs specify this is an acceptable method for now.